# Express Js : Multer upload files last file missing

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Using express server to upload files using multer. I am using `upload.fields()`

While trying to `console.log(req.files)`, The last field is missing. But all the files are being uploaded correctly. But in console I am not getting the last field in `req.files`
I am accessing the files because I need filename of each file for further use cases after upload.

```
 app.post("/upload", upload.fields([{ name: "field1" },{ name: "field2" },{ name: "field3" },]), async (req, res) => {

          console.log(req.files);    
    );
```

In the output for field3, I am only getting fieldname. No data related to the file is shown. Can someone tell me where I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include `enctype` to the form from where you are uploading the file from

```html
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="field1" />
  <input type="file" name="field2" />
  <input type="file" name="field3" />
</form>
```

Comment: Its already included.